# How do I launch/publish my website? ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, web

I'm new to web development and just built my first website with .Net Core. It's primarily HTML, CSS, and JavaScript with a little C# for a contact form.

Without recommending any service providers (question will be taken down), how do I go about deploying the website? The more details the better as I have no idea what I'm doing haha.

Edit: I am definitely going to go with a service provider, however the business I am building the website for doesn't have a large budget so I want to find the best provider at the lowest cost.

Comment: I've supplemented DanielG's answer by providing deployment in 3 scenarios.

Comment: You'd better tell us more from your side, such as why `dotnet run` isn't enough for you at this very moment. You can then move on to `dotnet publish` and a local web server as Microsoft documented in all details https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/?view=aspnetcore-6.0 It's nice that you understand what kind of questions are likely to be taken down, but when a question like this indicates you need more time on the official documentation or a good book it can be taken down too.

Comment: @LexLi Again, I'm new to web development and agree I should definitely look more into the documentation. I had been referencing the docs to help build, but wasn't aware of the documentation to deploy. Thanks for the pointer in the right direction!

Comment: What I hope is that you learned something from the experience of your questions being taken down. It's not because Stack Overflow isn't the place for questions, but it is more a place for certain types of questions. For example, if a question like this one can be easily solved by search engines (as "How do I launch/publish my website? ASP.NET Core" should easily trigger useful links including the one I pasted above), then you should rely more on those search engines to guide you through. Specific questions (and especially those nobody asked before) are more than welcome here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Daniel,

As you suspect, this is a bit of a loaded question as there are so many approaches. One approach is to use App Services within Microsoft Azure. You can create a free trial Azure account to start that includes a 200.00 credit, which is more than enough to do all of this for free. Then, using the Azure Management Portal, create an App Service (also free) on an App Service Plan in a region that makes sense for you (i.e. US West). Once you do that, you can download what is called a Publish Profile from within the App Service's Management Portal in Azure.

If you're using Visual Studio, for example, you can then right click your project and "Publish" it (deploy to the cloud, or the App Service you just created). One option in that process is to import an Azure Publish Profile, which you can do with the one you just downloaded. This makes it really simple. The Publish Profile is really just connection information to your Azure App Service (open it in Notepad to see). It will chug for a bit and then publish and load the app for you. You can also get to the hosted version of your app by clicking the Url of the app in the App Service management portal on the main page.

This may be oversimplifying what you need to do, but this is a valid direction to take. AWS and others have similar approaches.

Again, tons of ways to do this, but this is a free approach. :-) I don't consider Azure a Service Provider in the sense that you asked us not to. Instead, I wanted to outline one turn-key approach with specific details on how to get there.

You can find specific steps in a lot of places, such as this link:

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/deploying-your-web-app-using-azure-app-service/

Comment: Op don't want to use  any services from service provider, like azure and aws.

Comment: Thanks for the help! It's not that I don't want to use any service providers, the last time I asked for a service provider, stackoverflow removed my question because it violated their TOS.

Answer (score 0):

DanielG's answer is useful, but you mentioned you don't want use any services from service provider.

Usually, there are only three ways to deploy the program,

> **first one** is the app service provided by the service provider mentioned by DanielG,

---

```
**Benefits of using service provider products:**

1. Very friendly to newbies, follow the documentation to deploy the application in a few minutes.

2. It offers a very stable, scalable service that monitors the health of our website.

3. We can get their technical support.

**Shortcoming**

It is a paid service, and although Azure's service has a free quota, it will run out.

**Suggestion**

 It is recommended that websites that are officially launched use the services of service providers.
```

---

> **second one** is to use fixed IP for access (it seems that fixed iPv4 IP is not provided in network operations),

---

```
**Benefits of using fixed IP:**

If there is a fixed IP address, or if the carrier supports iPv6, we can deploy our website, and the public network can access it. And if you have domain, it also can support https.

**Shortcoming**

1. There are cybersecurity risks and are vulnerable to attack.
2. Without perfect website health monitoring, all problems need to be checked by yourself, and it is very troublesome to achieve elastic expansion.

**Suggestion**

 It is generally not recommended because there is no fixed IP under normal circumstances. Broadband operators used to offer it, but now it doesn't.

 If you are interested, you can try ipv6 to test.
```

---

> **the last one** is to use tools such as ngrok or frp for intranet penetration.

---

```
**Benefits of using intranet penetration:**

Free intranet penetration services such as ngrok, the URL generated by each run is not fixed, and there are some limitations, such as a new URL will be generated after a certain period of time, which is enough for testing.

Of course you can purchase the service of this tool, which provides fixed URLs and supports https.

**Shortcoming (same as the second one)**

**Suggestion**

 The functional implementation is the same as the second suggestion, and the physical devices used by the website are all their own. The intranet penetration tool (ngrok, or frp) solves the problem of not having a fixed IP, providing a URL that you can access.

 There are few users and the demand for web services is not high, so it is recommended that individual users or small business users use ngrok and frp in this scenario. Generally suitable for OA use in small businesses.
```

---

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned that I am open (and most likely) to use service providers, I just didn't want my question taken down from violating the TOS. Thanks for your reply!